# Chrome 58 on Android : bug with getUserMedia

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, getusermedia

I created an Ionic 2 application that use `getUserMedia` to get the local video stream. The application worked correctly on Chrome 57 on Android but since the update of Chrome on Android (version 58) I get an error when I use `getUserMedia`.

Here my code to get the local video stream :

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia){
            // Ask permission to use camera    
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission( (status) => {
                if (cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
                    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, (stream) => {
                        let video = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('localVideo');
                        video.srcObject =  stream;
                    }, (err) => {
                        console.error("getUserMedia::Error ", err.name);
                    });
                }
            }, (error) => {
                console.error("askRuntimePermissionCamera::Error", error);
            }, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA);
        } else {
            console.error("WebRTC not supported");
        }
```

And here the error message :

```
getUserMedia::Error  TrackStartError
```

Anyone can help me ?

Damien

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find anything out ?

Comment: Yes to solve this issue I used Crosswalk

Comment: @DamienLD Do you know why that was required to fix this? I am having the same issue using Twilio video library.

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg I don't know why that was required sorry.

Comment: Hey @DamienLD - it was solved for me using Crosswalk because I was testing on an older Android device which did not support WebRTC.  The same would be true if you were using any iOS device.  Cheers!